# Blob value showing empty object

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, blob

I have been trying to save a blob file in the backend using Laravel and Vue but unable to.

When I return all the response to see what I uploaded, I see that the blob field is empty. Also, using the vue devtool, it show `Blob`.

The file I'm using to upload is in a modal: `CampaignModal.vue`. That is a child component of the `CampaignMessages.vue`.

Below is the template for the modal.

```
<template>
 <div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="input-field col s12">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue right" href="#modal1">Message</a>
       </div>
   </div>

   <div id="modal1" class="modal">
       <div class="modal-content" style="height: 700px;">
           <h5>Add Message</h5>

           <div class="row">
               <div class="input-field col s12">
                   <textarea name="text" id="input-message" v-model="text" class="materialize-textarea"  data-length="200"></textarea>
                   <label for="input-message">Message</label>
               </div>
           </div>

           <div class="row">
               <div class="input-field col m6">
                   <datetime
                           placeholder="Select start date"
                           type="datetime"
                           v-model="startTime"
                           input-format="DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm"
                           input-class="my-input-class"
                           auto-continue
                           auto-close
                           required>

                   </datetime>

               </div>
               <div class="input-field col m6">
                   <datetime
                           placeholder="Select end date"
                           type="datetime"
                           v-model="endTime"
                           input-format="DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm"
                           input-class="my-input-class"
                           auto-continue
                           auto-close
                           required>

                   </datetime>
               </div>
           </div>

           <div class="row">
               <div class="col m6">
                   <div class="file-field input-field">
                       <div class="btn blue">
                           <span>Image</span>
                           <input type="file" id="input-image" name="image" @change="refreshImage" accept="image/*">
                           <!--<img :src="imageUrl" height="150">-->
                       </div>
                       <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                           <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload image">
                       </div>
                       <img id="image-thumb" name="image-thumb" width="100px" class="image-thumbnail img-responsive" :src="imageUrl"/>
                   </div>
               </div>

               <div class="col m6">
                   <div class="file-field input-field">
                       <div class="btn blue">
                           <span>Video</span>
                           <input type="file" id="input-video" @change="refreshVideo" accept=".mov,.mp4">
                       </div>
                       <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                           <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload video">
                       </div>
                       <video id="video-preview" width="100px" type="video/mp4" controls class="video-preview img-responsive" :src="videoUrl"/>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>

           <div class="row">
               <div class="input-field col s12">
                   <button @click.prevent="addMessage" class="modal-action 
                       modal-close waves-effect waves-light btn blue right">
                       Add Message
                   </button>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>

    </div>

  </div>


</template>
```

Below is the script

```
<script>
import { Datetime } from 'vue-datetime';

export default {
    components: { Datetime },

    data() {
        return {
            //messages: [],
            text: '',
            imageUrl: '',
            imageBlob: '',
            videoUrl: '',
            videoBlob: '',
            startTime: '',
            endTime: '',
        }
    },

    methods: {
        reset() {
            this.text = '';
            this.imageUrl = '';
            this.imageBlob = '';
            this.videoUrl = '';
            this.videoBlob = '';
            this.startTime = '';
            this.endTime = '';
        },

        refreshImage() {
            let comp = this;
            this.readObjectUrl(document.getElementById('input-image'), 
             function (url, blob) {
                comp.imageUrl = url;
                comp.imageBlob = blob;
            });
        },

        refreshVideo() {
            let comp = this;
            this.readObjectUrl(document.getElementById('input-video'), 
            function (url, blob) {
                comp.videoUrl = url;
                comp.videoBlob = blob;
                comp.playVideo(url);
            });
        },

        playVideo(url) {
            let video = document.getElementById('video-preview');
            video.preload = 'metadata';
            // Load video in Safari / IE11
            if (url) {
                video.muted = false;
                video.playsInline = true;
                video.play();
            }
        },

        addMessage() {
            this.$emit('added-message', this);
            this.reset();
        },

        // Read a file input as a data URL.
        readDataUrl(input, callback) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                let fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = function () {
                    callback(fileReader.result);
                };
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
            else {
                callback(null);
            }
        },

        // Read a file input as an object url.
        readObjectUrl(input, callback) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                let fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = function () {
                    let blob = new Blob([fileReader.result], {type: 
                    input.files[0].type});
                    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    callback(url, blob);
                };
                fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(input.files[0]);
            }
            else {
                callback(null);
            }

        },

    }

  }
 </script>
```

And my submit method looks like this:

```
submit() {
            let data = new FormData();
            data.append('description', this.description);
            for (let index in this.boards) {
                if (this.boards.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
                    data.append('displays[' + index + ']', 
                    this.boards[index]);
                }
            }
            for (let index in this.messages) {
                if (this.messages.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
                    data.append('messages[' + index + '][text]', 
                     this.messages[index].text);
                    data.append('messages[' + index + '][image]', 
                    this.messages[index].imageBlob);
                    data.append('messages[' + index + '][video]', 
                    this.messages[index].videoBlob);
                    data.append('messages[' + index + '][startTime]', 
                    this.messages[index].startTime);
                    data.append('messages[' + index + '][endTime]', 
                    this.messages[index].endTime);
                }
            }

            axios.post('/campaign/', data).then(response => {
                this.feedback = response.data;
            }).catch(error=>{
                this.errors = error
            });
        }
```

Below is what I'm getting on the vuedev tool.
[image: Vuedev tool image]
[image: the response]

How do I get to save the blob on my server?

Comment: looks like you're trying to upload the result of calling `URL.createObjectURL` - if you read the documentation for that method, you should see why that doesn't work .. *creates a DOMString containing a URL **representing the object** given in the parameter* ... it's a string, that represents the object, it isn't a file that you can send to a server

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't seem to know what next to do. Could you please give me a hint on how to get the image saved on my server? I have been stuck with this issue for long.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but Wow where did you get this `readObjectUrl` function from? It is completely useless except if your goal is to make as many computation and occupy as many memory as you can. A File is a Blob. You can rewrite it as  `readObjectUrl(input, callback){var f=input.files[0]; callback(URL.createObjectURL(f, f)}` or simply get rid of it, because now, it's synchronous. (The **only** really rare case where this function would make sense would be to keep the Blob alive in case your user removes it from their disk after they selected it. And IMO this would be questionable).

Comment: And to your question, it should work as you are doing it. I don't know Laravel, and you don't show how you tried to access these Blobs, but with vanilla PHP you would access this file through `file_get_contents($_FILES["messages"]['tmp_name'][0]['image'])`. And to get its name, it would be in `$_FILES["messages"]['name'][0]['image']`. Note how you must navigate your own structure only after you accessed the `$_FILES['user_file']['file_property']`.

Comment: Thanks @Kalido
I'm using vanilla PHP to access the files. However, accessing the file name with `$_FILES["messages"]['name'][0]['image']` still returns `blob`

Comment: Hello @Dan Gamble